# nftables: forward HTTP traffic to a box behind NAT

Tags: debian, nftables

I have a debian system as a gateway. My nftables.conf is pretty simple:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter;
        }
        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter;
        }
        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority filter;
        }
}

table ip nat {
        chain prerouting {
                type nat hook prerouting priority filter; policy accept;
        }

        chain postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                oifname "enp5s0" masquerade
        }
}
```

Now, I want to modify it to redirect incoming traffic from the internet to port 80 to the 192.168.1.3 host.

I have tried adding `tcp dport 80 dnat to 192.168.1.3` in the `nat:prerouting` chain, but it also redirects outgoing traffic. Adding `iffname "enp5s0"` doesn't seem to work at all. I.e this:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter;
        }
        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter;
        }
        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority filter;
        }
}

table ip nat {
        chain prerouting {
                type nat hook prerouting priority filter; policy accept;
                iifname enp5s0 tcp dport 80 dnat to 192.168.1.3
        }

        chain postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                #oifname "enp5s0" masquerade
                masquerade
        }
}
```

Any idea what's the correct approach? Googling hasn't helped much

Thanks!

Comment: Your 2nd ruleset has TWO changes: the dnat rule, and the masquerade rule not only for enp5s0 anymore. So what you describe doesn't reflect what you did. Can you fix the inconsistency? (please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/772193/edit) the question).

Comment: I can only assume enp5s0 is the WAN interface. Is that correct? And in addition, can you also describe in the question what test you are doing to check if it works or it doesn't work? A correct test should be done from remote: outside of your network. Not from within your network, nor from the gateway. But if that's what you did anyway, please also state it. You should provide a command (eg: nc/netcat or socat or curl ...) and IP addresses used for the test.